# Code formatting is missing on the mobile site

Tags: support, code-formatting, mobile-web

I wasn't able to format code and without formatting it was not allowing me to post answer.
Code was 5 to 10 lines.

What I feel proper app is missing and your mobile site doesn't have code formatting which makes hard posting Q n A.

I am using Lumia 820 Windows phone 8.1

May I know what are the alternatives for code formatting available for me from mobile? Might be I am missing something.

Comment: I *legitimately* doubt that any of the mobile Windows browsers are supported for this site.

Comment: You could use {} to format your code. Or just indent it by four spaces.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need a format-as-code button to use code formatting.  Just use one of the following two methods (which are what the format-as-code button uses anyway):

1. Surround `inline code` with backticks (`)
2. Use at least four spaces to indent

   ```
       block code
   ```

Block code also needs to be set apart from other text by blank lines.

However, I have to discourage posting questions from the mobile app.  Small screens and touch keyboards are not suited either for doing research before asking, or for fully explaining your problem and then proofreading before posting.  The mobile app is much more useful for reading questions and answers and getting notified when someone else interacts with any of your posts.  Even adding comments is a serious pain (for example, it doesn't give username suggestions when you type `@` to ping another user in the conversation).  Besides all that, phone data connections tend to be much less reliable, so you're at risk of losing all your work.

Besides this, you should never, ever be posting code in a question unless you've already tried to compile (or run, if an interpreted language) it yourself.  How are you going to do that on a phone?  Online compiler sites are even more inferior compared to a computer-hosted development environment, when used from a phone, than SO is.

Just use a full-sized laptop or desktop and the main website when asking a question -- you'll be much happier with the experience.  (The mobile app on a tablet docked with a mouse and keyboard is a reasonable alternative, if you know the shortcuts, [as I noted here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283516/103167))

Comment: I agree, but some questions we can answer from mobile. Thanks for help.

Comment: Could not find backticks (`) on iPhone.

Comment: @HyperZ Hold down the apostrophe: http://i.stack.imgur.com/L60ly.png

Answer (score 0):

While it’s best to be posting (and writing code) on a device that has a physical keyboard, there are a few things that make the mobile web experience a bit better with regards to this. First of all, I suggest switching to the full, responsive site:

[image: screenshot of footer full site link]

I’m not completely satisfied with the mobile experience on either version (for reasons unrelated to making code blocks), but there is an advantage to using the responsive full site instead of the “mobile site”: you get the toolbar when writing posts. This means you can use the code button to format your code.

(It’s also worth noting that the “mobile site“ will be removed at some point, leaving only the responsive full site.)

Another way to easily get code blocks is to use code fences (though that wouldn’t have worked in 2015 when this question was asked). On mobile I prefer using tildes because they are easier to type than backticks:

```
~~~js
// Write code here. 
~~~
```